# GpsStatus.Listener registers only if GPS is on

Tags: android, gps, widget

I have a widget that displays the current user location using a LocationManager. i conserve battery by disabling a local broadcast manager for location updates through a system broadcast manager that indicates if the screen is on or off. To accompany the battery saving effort, i am trying to implement a GpsStatus.Listener to tell me if the gps has been turned on or off so i can use it in my locationmanager. Everything works perfectly if i load the widget ONLY IF THE GPS IS ON. The GpsStatus.Listener fails to fire if the widget is loaded when the GPS IS OFF. Obviously there is an imperefct workaround (load with gps on) but i am curious and ask why the listener doesn't work if the gps is off at runtime. I am using os 4.0.3 and my manifest includes fine location. ta.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    // Get all ids
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "running......");
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

    ServicesManager = new MyLocationManager(context);
    streetAddress = new CellAddress(context, ServicesManager);
    ServicesManager.lm.addGpsStatusListener(myGPSListener);

    filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiveUpdatedLocation, 
            new IntentFilter("sendUpdatedLocation"));


    if (!(ServicesManager.isInternet()))
    {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Address not available" + "\n\n" +
                                    "Check data connection....");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
    else
    {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, streetAddress.address$);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate");
}

GpsStatus.Listener myGPSListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() 
{

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
    {
        if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED)
        {
        Log.d(TAG, "GPS Started");  
        } else if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GPS Stopped");
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: To clarify: Your GPS is off and above code is executed and you expect the GPSListener to fire GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED although GPS was already turned off by that time? In this case: those GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_X are live events if I am not mistaken - you need to have your GpsStatus.Listener registered in order to receive those events when they happen (not after that) - or am I misunderstanding sth?

Comment: Same problem here: [GpsStatus.Listener works only if GPS is on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259039/gpsstatus-listener-works-only-if-gps-is-on)