# GpsStatus.Listener works only if GPS is on

Tags: android, gps, listener

in my App I have a [GpsStatus.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) to receive events when the user enables or disables GPS. Everything works fine if **GPS is on before I start the app**. In this case I receive a [GPS_EVENT_STARTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#GPS_EVENT_STARTED) or a [GPS_EVENT_STOPPED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#GPS_EVENT_STOPPED) everytime I toggle GPS on or off.

The problem is if **GPS is off while app is starting**. In this case I don't receive an event if I toggle GPS on or off.

Can someone explain that to me?

Here is my code:

```
public class GPSTracker implements android.location.GpsStatus.Listener {

    private final Context context;
    private final LocationListener locListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    public GPSTracker(Context context, LocationListener locListener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.locListener = locListener; 
            setupGPS();
    }

    private void setupGPS() {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);                
            locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(!isGPSEnabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "GPS disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {        
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, locListener);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            Log.e("onGpsStatusChanged", event+""); 
            switch(event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    Log.e("onGpsStatusChanged", "GPS_EVENT_STARTED");
                    break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    Log.e("onGpsStatusChanged", "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED");
                    break;
            }
    }
```

So, my logcat output is (if GPS is on while starting):

- GpsStatusChanged(24638): 1    // app starts
- GpsStatusChanged(24638): GPS_EVENT_STARTED
- GpsStatusChanged(24638): 4    // searching for fixes
- GpsStatusChanged(24638): 4
- GpsStatusChanged(24638): 2    // toggle GPS off
- GpsStatusChanged(24638): GPS_EVENT_STOPED

Output with GPS off: nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `LocationListener` has been provided with:

[`onProviderDisabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onProviderDisabled%28java.lang.String%29),[`onProviderEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29) and [`onStatusChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) for exactly this purpose.

`GpsStatus.Listener` delivers info about GPS service's inner workings. It is not to be used for telling the status pf GPS Provider.

`LocationListener` delivers info about providers. The moment you register `LocationListener` with location provider, `onProviderEnabled()`/`onProviderDisabled()` is called accordingly, and your app can always tell when GPS is turned on or off.

Try this:

```
public class test extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,10,this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(s)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"GPS on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(s)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"GPS off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my question is about GpsStatus.Listener ;-)

Comment: @Namenlos And `GpsStatus.Listener` is NOT the proper thing to detect **provider setting changes**. That's what I'm explaining.

Comment: "GpsStatus.Listener delivers info about GPS service's inner workings. It is not to be used for telling the status of GPS Provider." - Thanks, that was what I wanted to hear. The class overview ["Used for receiving notifications when GPS status has changed"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) has confused me a bit.