# Android how to listen the GPS state change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-location

I want to listen the state change of GPS dynamically, just like use broadcast. If I use `mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`, that can't get state change infomation in real time. I think maybe use `GpsStatus.Listener()`, but dont't know how to achieve it at my fragment.

Comment: find more about [GpsStatus.Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259039/gpsstatus-listener-works-only-if-gps-is-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to GPS changes by implementing LocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    //initialize locationManager

    public void init() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }


}
```